# How do I write deffensive programs with purescript Aff

Tags: purescript

I'm kind of new on purescript and I was experimenting with effects and particular async effects.

One of the things I love the most about FP and strict compilers like the one purescript has is that it enforces you to handle all possible results, in particular when you define that something can fail. If you for example are using an Either, you need to tell the program what to do in case you have the `Right` answer or an error.

When I first looked at effects I liked the concept of `actions` and `handlers` and that if a part of your code needs to throw an exception (I imagine this is the last resource you want to use) you need to declare it using something like

```
someAction :: forall eff. Eff (exception :: EXCEPTION | eff)
```

and that you can define a handler that removes that effect so you know that from that point onwards you don't have to care about exceptions.

But doing some basic tests with the `Aff` monad and the `purescript-node-fs-aff` library I got some unexpected results.

If I do something like this

```
main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, buffer :: BUFFER, fs :: FS | e) Unit
main = do
  _ <- launchAff $ readAndLog "./non-existing-file" 
  pure unit

readAndLog :: forall eff. String -> Aff (fs :: FS, console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit
readAndLog path = do
  str <- readTextFile UTF8 path
  log str
```

If the file doesn't exists the program will terminate throwing an exception and there is nothing telling me that this code can fail, and that I should try to protect my program agaisnt that failure.

I can in fact be a little more defensive and use a `catchError`, but I was expecting that at least the compiler fail saying I wasn't taking exception as a possible side effect.

```
main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, buffer :: BUFFER, fs :: FS | e) Unit
main = do
  _ <- launchAff $ readAndLog "./non-existing-file" `catchError` (\e -> log ("buu: " <> message e))
  pure unit

readAndLog :: forall eff. String -> Aff (fs :: FS, console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit
readAndLog path = do
  str <- readTextFile UTF8 path
  log str
```

Ideally I would like to do something like `Either` and be responsible to handle the particular errors the operation may have. For example when I read a file I should expect to have an error like `ENOENT` (file does not exist) or `EACCES` (you don't have access), etc. If I want to ignore the particular reason and just log that it failed it's my choice but the type system should enforce me to handle it.

Comment: In the pursecript channel I was refered to this issue https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-aff/issues/137

Comment: The problem really is that `launchAff` swallows the errors. It should require the caller to provide instructions (i.e. callback) for what to do with errors, but instead it just ignores them.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple facets to your question.

First, effect rows are soon being removed from standard practice. That has begun with [`v0.12`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases/tag/v0.12.0-rc1). Here is [a public opinion poll](https://twitter.com/paf31/status/908760073303764993) on the matter. The discussions are on GitHub. In a nutshell: the burden outweighs the benefit.

Then there is the problem of knowing which exceptions could be thrown. If you use 3rd party JavaScript anywhere, that will be difficult. In this case I recommend thinking of known exceptions as a lower bound of all exceptions which may be thrown. In other words, even if you catch all known exceptions you must also make a default catch to account for the unknown.

Take a look at Nathan Faubion's [purescript-checked-exceptions](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-checked-exceptions/1.0.0) library. This shows how to apply checked exceptions to an ExceptT interface.

I have similar work done for JavaScript's native exceptions which is appropriate for FFI. Unfortunately that is not published yet but I will hopefully be able to do so soon. At least you can know it is possible.

The final facet is Aff itself. Unfortunately, Aff is not designed for arbitrary exceptions. It only supports the `Error` type (i.e. the JavaScript type of the same name). Therefore, you would be better to use purescript-checked-exceptions with Aff to add checked exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the great comment! Too bad they are taking out the eff rows, I liked that feature. I decided not to use Aff basically because it treats all errors as Error, and I like to have specific more descriptive errors. Not for js code run trough FFI, but for my own code.

Comment: @HernanRajchert ExceptV is a monad transformer. Therefore, you can stack it with Aff to add checked exceptions. You can essentially ignore Aff's error handling features in that case. If you need scheduling, Aff is still a great choice.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler would not tell you that because exceptions are assimilated by the `Aff` machinery in the library you are using. Here are the relevant pieces:

```
readTextFile = toAff2 A.readTextFile
toAff2 f a b = toAff (f a b)
toAff p      = makeAff \e a -> p $ either e a
```

Where `A.readTextFile` is [the async version](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-node-fs/4.0.1/docs/Node.FS.Async#v:readTextFile) in the Node library.

The expression `either e a` is where it happens. As `Aff` has a `MonadError`, your only recourse is indeed to catch the error. That said, I completely agree with you that the effect should expose the fact exceptions may be thrown. For some reason, only [the synchronous version](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-node-fs/4.0.1/docs/Node.FS.Sync#v:readTextFile) of the Node library does.

Comment: From what I could understand talking in the slack community, the reason that launchAff doesn't have the exception effect is that the exception comes async.

Comment: It still feels like an oversight, doesn't it? Nothing prevents the Aff team to provide a type to denote asynchronous effects, e.g. `foreign import data AsyncEffect :: # Effect -> Effect`.